# AUTO INCREMENT is skipping a number every time

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I have a `MYSQL DATABASE` with a table for activities with an ID which is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`.

I noticed that the auto incremented primary key values for the activities are incrementing by 2 instead of 1 when I use my php webservice. When I try it in `phpmyAdmin` it works fine.

Here is my php webservice:

```
<?php
include("wt_dbconnection.php");

$json = $_POST["Json1"];

$jsondata = json_decode($dson,true);

$Beginningtime=$jsondata['Beginningtime'];
$Endtime =$jsondata['Endtime'];

$sql = "insert into Activities(Beginningtime,Endtime)
values('$Beginningtime', '$Endtime')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo ("error");
}
else
{
echo ("done");
}
?>
```

I don't know what I have done wrong..

EDIT 1:

[Data Structure   (It is in German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApaaC.png)

EDIT 2:

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `Activities` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Beginningtime` date NOT NULL,
 `Endtime` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Do you have (or had in the past) replication in mysql? This is typical to avoid collision on autoincrement values in a master-master environment. Please post or check your data structure.

Comment: Can you include the table schema in your question?

Comment: This shouldn't be critical in any way, autoincrement is about trying to give you a unique id value, not necessarily consecutive id values; and your code should never be dependent on a particular patter of ids

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah I know but I want to know whats wrong

Comment: can to share your table schema. the create/modify table script

Comment: @DST - Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>;` and show the results of that

Comment: Just a heads up, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  It's not related to your sequence number issue, but you should certainly look into fixing it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, the problem was in the c# code. Before I send data to the webservice, i check if the url is reachable, this was the problem.

here the code:

```
        public static bool urlisreachable(System.Uri url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```